# Any way to lockdown a virtual comm port to a specific baud rate?

Tags: winapi, virtual-machine, com0com

I'm using [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) for virtual comm ports.

I'm trying to test some software, whereby I am replacing a bunch of physical com ports with virtual ones. The software check through each one a determines it baud rate and from tries a different software function.

But, when using virtual ports assigned a specific baud rate and checking through for the specific baud rate, my virtual port's baud rate changes due to the checking.

Is there any way to make sure that a virtual comm port's baud rate is locked down and doesn't change?

Comment: Baud rate doesn't even mean anything for a virtual com port.  Are you asking for some sort of baud detection?  Usually each side configures the baud rate independently.  Autobaud allows a receiver to match its baud rate to an ongoing transmission.  But that requires special hardware that a virtual com port does not emulate.

Comment: In addition to not simulating baud rate I would also expect the connection framing (bits-per-character, parity and stop bits) to be meaningless when using a virtual serial driver.

Comment: com0com does have baud rate simulation although it is disabled by default. But I don't know how to lock it down, or even set the default baud rate (since the "Port Settings" property page doesn't appear in the Device Manager for com0com ports).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir com0com _does_ emulate connection framing. This tripped me up; it was stripping the high bit from every character because I had not configured the TX port end for 8 bit data.